# Which m numbers in the range [1, k] have sum equal to n

Tags: algorithms

Given the values of $n, k, m$, you have to check if there are $m$ distinct numbers in the range from 1 to $k$ have the sum $n$ or not ?

$n$ represents the required sum
$k$ represents numbers range(1,2,3,... to k).
$m$ is the number of elements in the range from 1 to $k$ that has the sum $n$.

Example: n = 12, k = 8, m = 3 ==> there are 3 numbers in the range from 1 to 8 that have the sum 12 which are 2,3,7.

The problem is taken from hackerrank and called [bonetrousle](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/bonetrousle).

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: Hi @Evil, don't worry it is a practice and I got to this stack to get algorithmic and scientific sense behind the problem. 
You can check the full code here https://github.com/PeterASteele/HackerRankProblems/blob/master/Bonetrousle.java

Comment: I think no as the problem stated above may have more solutions like.
3 4 5 ==> sum = 12
and
2 3 7 ==> sum = 12

Comment: Unique was about the numbers to avoid situation where we can pick 12 = 4 + 4 + 4.

Comment: yes the numbers should be unique. the answer 4 + 4 + 4 is incorrect.

Answer (score 5):

Hint:

1. What is the *smallest* number that can be represented as the sum of $m$ distinct integers from $1$ to $k$?
2. What is the *largest* number that can be represented as the sum of $m$ distinct integers from $1$ to $k$?
3. Can all numbers in between be so represented?